# What is the 'xmessage' command equivalent on macOS?

Tags: bash, unix

For Linux, there is a command `xmessage` which displays a message in a window. Does anyone know what is the equivalent one on macOS?

Comment: what computer do you have and what system are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## AppleScript

On macOS, displaying simple dialogs is possible with AppleScript:

```
/usr/bin/osascript -e "display dialog \"Hello world\""
```

See [Displaying Dialogs and Alerts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayDialogsandAlerts.html) in Apple's Mac Automation Scripting Guide.

Additional buttons, choices, and other limited interface elements can be added:

```
set theDialogText to "An error has occurred. Would you like to continue?"
display dialog theDialogText buttons {"Don't Continue", "Continue"} default button "Continue" cancel button "Don't Continue"
```

[image: AppleScript dialog box]

Answer (score -1):

There is an xmessage command on the Mac which does the same thing. The options may be different but there is a man page for xmessage.

Comment: That only works if you have [XQuartz](https://www.xquartz.org) (X Windows for macOS) installed; most people don't.